# Gedit, Evince has print disabled

Tags: 12.10, gedit, gtk3, 13.04, evince

Print menu command is disabled in evince and gedit. Print functionality works fine in other applications like Chrome, GIMP, Firefox. Ubuntu printer setup correctly recognizes my printer and scanner uses the the scanner from the printer device perfectly.

I noticed it in 12.10 and it is still there on upgrade to 13.04.

I even opened a bug for this but it has remained in incomplete state for too long.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evince/+bug/1085212

Comment: @maggotbrain linked the bug